# Hive Join returning zero records

Tags: join, hadoop, hive

I have two Hive tables and I am trying to join both of them. The tables are not clustered or partitioned by any field. Though the tables contain records for common key fields, the join query always returns 0 records. All the data types are 'string' data types.

The join query is simple and looks something like below

```
select count(*) cnt
from
fsr.xref_1 A join
fsr.ipfile_1 B 
on 
(
    A.co_no = B.co_no 
)
;
```

Any idea what could be going wrong? I have just one record (same value) in both the tables.

Below are my table definitions

```
CREATE TABLE xref_1 
(
co_no string
)
clustered by (co_no) sorted by (co_no asc) into 10 buckets
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;

CREATE TABLE ipfile_1
(
co_no string
)
clustered by (co_no) sorted by (co_no asc) into 10 buckets
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Comment: This should work, can you maybe give a more complete example using table definitions and real data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi You are using **Star Schema Join**. Please use your query like this:

```
SELET COUNT(*) cnt FROM A a JOIN B b ON (a.key1 = b.key1);
```

If still have issue Then use **MAPJOIN**:

```
set hive.auto.convert.join=true;
select count(*) from A join B on (key1 = key2)
```

Please see [Link](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.0.0.2/ds_Hive/optimize-joins.html) for more detail.

Comment: Wow ! Using the set option for mapjoin did the trick. I do not exactly understand how optimizing using Mapjoin has helped to produce correct results. Any clues ?

Comment: This is little bit tricky for me also. Please see above link and **https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/MapJoinOptimization** and **https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-joins.html#LanguageManualJoins-MapJoinRestrictions** for more clarification.